# Is it possible to create many instances of boost logger?

Tags: c++, logging, boost, boost-log

Since **Boost log** having many characteristics like thread- safe and etc., I want to know that can we able to create many instances of the logger.


    Because I read in document that Boost log creates only one instance. Is it true?


   Is there any **other logging library** which supports from **Windows XP or it may be platform independent**.


   Please Suggest your ideas and information that you may know.


   
Thanks,

   
AK.

Comment: Can you explain why you need **many** instances of the logger. You can have many sinks: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/tutorial/sinks.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to create many logger by using

```
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(tag_attr, "Tag", std::string)
```

or

```
BOOST_LOG_SCOPED_THREAD_TAG("Tag", tag_)
```

For more details, you can check the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39247778/boost-log-how-to-prevent-the-output-will-be-duplicated-to-all-added-streams-whe)

Comment: Yes , Finally I got the answer for What I need . Thank You very much .

Answer (score 0):

You can create as many loggers as you like, see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/tutorial/sources.html), for instance. However, there is only one logging core, and you cannot create multiple cores.

Comment: Can we make each logger to write in its own separate files ?                               If my question is wrong Please Explain me.

Comment: Yes, this is explained in the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34362871/use-channel-hiearchy-of-boost-log-for-severity-and-sink-filtering/34372526#34372526