# Boost Log: how to specify a synchronous sink with BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER_INIT

Tags: c++, logging, boost

I have been creating a log with the macro BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER_INIT as :

```
typedef src::severity_logger_mt<severity_level> logger_t;

BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER_INIT(logger, src::severity_logger_mt)
{
logger_t lg;
logging::add_common_attributes();
...
```

but I could not find out how to specify my logger has to use a synchronous sink
and enable auto-flushing after each log record written :-(

any idea on how to proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34362871/use-channel-hiearchy-of-boost-log-for-severity-and-sink-filtering/34372526#34372526) answer. You just create and configure the sink however you like and then set up filters so that the records from your logger are routed to the sink.